# In ApiPlatform, how can I preprocess some request header and make the resulting data available to MessageHandler objects?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

### Context

I am trying to migrate a Symfony 3 API using FosRestBundle to Symfony 7 and ApiPlatform. I've read ApiPlatform documentation and decided based on [Symfony Messenger Integration: CQRS and Async Message Processing](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/) that ApiPlatform was worth a try as there seemed to be a way to handle the non-CRUD parts of my API.

### Problem

Some of my non-CRUD endpoints expect a custom request header whose value must be processed, the resulting data being considered for authentication in addition to a JWT accessToken and then used in the `#[MessageHandler]` objects triggered by these requests. My idea would be to use an `EventSubscriber` to grab the header and process it, but then I am not sure how to :

1. Use the header information for authentication (i.e. return a 4xx `Response` if it does not meet certain criteria) only if the endpoint expects that header to be correctly set
2. Pass the processed header data to the `#[MessageHandler]` object handling the request.

### Attempted solutions

For part 1, I tried replicating the behavior of the current version of my API where the `EventSubscriber` uses introspection to determine if the target controller expects an argument matching the header data :

```php
        $controller = $event->getController();

        $method = new \ReflectionMethod($controller[0], $controller[1]);
        $parameter = $this->findParameterOfType(Device::class, $method);

        if (null !== $parameter) {
            if (!$event->getRequest()->headers->has('My-Header')) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException('Requires device authentication');
            }
        }
```

but with ApiPlatform/Messenger, the controller is always `MainController` so it won't work. I do not know if/how I could get the #[MessageHandler] object instead to implement the same solution. I also suppose there could be a *config* solution involving a specific firewall for those endpoints, but I couldn't find how to begin coding such a thing.

For part 2, I guess the easiest way would be to write the processed header information into the request attribute bag. Then I could retrieve it in the #[MessageHandler] object using the `RequestStack`. But I am under the impression that it is not a very clean way to do it.

If someone has a hint as to how to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated!